# ngx-quill issue with Language tool extension

Tags: javascript, angular, rich-text-editor, quill, languagetool

I am using ngx-quill-editor as a rich text editor for my angular application.
I am not getting Value from quill as expected while using Language tool chrome extension. It works fine otherwise.

I didn't find any issue raised for support of quill editor with Language tool.

The value I get from quill editor while using Language tool is like this:

```
<lt-div spellcheck="false" class="lt-highlighter__wrapper" style="width: 538px; height: 155px;"><canvas class="lt-highlighter__canvas" width="538" height="155" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;"></canvas></lt-div>
```

When a user type 'Hello world' in editor, then I should get a value like

Hello world

But I am not getting value as expected.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We're (LanguageTool) looking into it. It's definitely caused by our Browser Extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the style as an attribute like so:

```
<quill-editor name="content" [modules]="{toolbar: toolBarOptions}" [style]="{height: '300px'}"></quill-editor>
```

Note toolbarOptions is an object in the related typescript